# Translate Java Code to Php Code

Tags: java, php

I am trying to write a example code of generate a signature to php, the sample is on java but i am doing something wrong. Can anyone help me?

The sample is:

```
String userId; 
String applicationKey; // E.g. "196087a1-e815-4bc4-8984-60d8d8a43f1d";
String applicationSecret; // E.g. "oYdgGRXoxEuJhGDY2KQ/HQ==";
long sequence; // fetch and increment last used sequence
String toSign = userId + applicationKey + sequence + applicationSecret;
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String signature = Base64.encodeBase64String(hash).trim();
```

My code is:

```
$userId="User";
$applicationKey="MyappKey";
$applicationSecret="MySecretKey";
$sequence=1;
$stringToSign=$userId.$applicationKey.$sequence.$applicationSecret;
$hash = sha1($stringToSign,true);
$signature = trim(base64_encode($hash));
```

Is in Java

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The same in PHP that

```
$hash1 = sha1($stringToSign,true);
```

And the Java `Base64.encodeBase64String(hash).trim();` is the same in php that `trim(base64_encode($hash));`

the problem is when i execute the java code and get the output is not the same that the php code.

Comment: You should update your Java code to make the same assignments as your PHP code; as StefanBeike points out, your Java code isn't valid because of uninitialized variables.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." "I am doing something wrong" is not a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments but i am trying to write in PHP the java code is giving to me. It is in https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#authenticationbyclientaccesstoapplicationsecret if the Java code is wrong is new to me because i want it in php and i dont know to much about Java. That is why i am asking here.

Comment: Right. But what makes you think you are doing something wrong? An error message? Unexpected output? Self doubt? You need to actually be specific about what your problem is; not knowing enough about a language is not a specific problem.

Comment: If i execute in Java and get the output is not the same as the php code :(

Comment: OK - so what is your input, your Java output and your PHP output?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$signature = trim(base64_encode(**$hash**));
```

Comment: Thank you Kurt but was a mistake copying the code, this lane is good in my code :(